# Event Specific Webform Submissions

Tags: 7, webforms

I have a bunch of events that users should be allowed to register to. But I am trying to use one basic form that asks for the following fields:

```
First Name
Last Name
Phone Number
Email
Gender
```

I was wondering if there is a way to connect that form to a specific event. Is it possible to have a submissions field that is hidden from the user that auto populates with the node ID or something similar to that approach?

Any help would be much appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use [entityform](https://drupal.org/project/entityform)s instead of webforms.

And then, you should enable entity tokens and [Field default token](https://drupal.org/project/field_default_token) modules.

Now you can add a text field to your entityform, which contains URL of the current page as the default value.

After that, you may hide that field by CSS.

Answer (score 0):

I would say add an [entity reference](http://drupal.org/project/entityreference) field to the webform that can reference the event nodes.

Then you could use the [entity reference prepopulate](https://drupal.org/project/entityreference_prepopulate) module, which will allow you to add an extra parameter to links that point to the webform that will prepopulate the field.

You can decide what to do when you prepopulate the field, including hiding that field from the user.